# Inner joining on the same table twice in PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join, inner-join

I am wrestling with the following query on my PostgreSQL database, built initially with the Doctrine Query Builder (but that's not relevant here).

I have an entity called "Course" which has multiple records in the "Log" table.

The record for `log.resumeComplete` has a date and the record for `log.activated` has a date.

In this one query I am looking to pull out records that have a `log.activated` date older than X and a `log.resumeComplete` older than Y. Importantly, some "Course" records have no corresponding `log.resumeComplete` record in the Log table.

Is there a way I can get this information with one query?

```
SELECT s0_.slug AS slug, s0_.status AS status, a2_.time AS resumeTime
FROM Course s0_ 
    INNER JOIN Log a1_ ON (a1_.course_id = s0_.id) 
    INNER JOIN Log a2_ ON (s0_.id = a2_.course_id AND a2_.type = 'log.resumeComplete')
WHERE s0_.status = 'active' 
    AND s0_.currentsss = '72' 
    AND a1_.type = 'log.activated'
    AND a1_.time < '2020-05-31 14:25:31'   
    AND a2_.time IS NULL OR a2_.time < '2020-07-11 14:25:31'
ORDER BY s0_.id ASC;
```

Comment: I don't think this can be done much better, except you should try to get rid of that `OR` - you could use `coalesce`, which can be indexed.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for the comment. My attempt at using `OR` here was because not every record will have a "resumeComplete" time, but when I introduce the `IS NULL` the query disregards the status of "active" and returns results that I don't want. What is your suggestion for using the `coalesce` function?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Sorry for you having to delete your post, perhaps I didn't explain the problem clearly. :-(

Comment: That's my fault as much as yours, so don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

This query *should* work (got not fiddle/test-set):

changed:

- inner join => left join
- first join-conditions moved up
- "or" works on ALL pervious conditions, rendering them useless. "( )" required
- maybe implicit type-conversion (time < string), bad for indexing. not corrected, no fiddle

SQL

```
SELECT s0_.slug AS slug, s0_.status AS status, a2_.time AS resumeTime
FROM Course s0_ 
    INNER JOIN Log a1_ ON (a1_.course_id = s0_.id and AND a1_.type = 'log.activated')  
    left JOIN Log a2_ ON (a2_.course_id = s0_.id AND a2_.type = 'log.resumeComplete')
WHERE s0_.status = 'active' 
    AND s0_.currentsss = '72' 
    
    AND a1_.time < '2020-05-31 14:25:31'   
    AND (a2_.time IS NULL OR a2_.time < '2020-07-11 14:25:31') -- this type of comparison might cause an implicet conversion of a2_.time to varchar. bad
ORDER BY s0_.id ASC;
```